# A lot of undefined OpenGL functions under Linux despite using glew

Tags: c, linux, opengl, glew, freeglut

I am trying to get my first project running with OpenGL under fedora 36. For this I am using the libraries "freeglut.h" and "glew.h".
However, with many functions like:

- glBindBuffer
- glGenBuffer
- glEnableVertexAttribArray
- glVertexAttribPointer
- glDisableVertexAttribArray
- glBufferData

the error Visual Studio Codes shows me, is that these functions are undefined.

Other things, like

- GLuint
- glClear
- glDrawArrays
- glSwapBuffers

seem to work just fine.

I try to compile the project with the following command:

```
gcc firstProject.cpp -o firstProject -lGLEW -lGL -lGLU -lglut
```

But I get multiple errors, that for example glBindBuffer was not declared in this scope.

Here is a snipped from my firstProject.cpp:

```
    #include <GL/freeglut.h>
    #include <GL/glew.h>
    #include <stdio.h>

    GLuint VBO;

    static void renderScene() {
      glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

      glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);

      glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

      glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

      glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, 1);

      glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);

      glutSwapBuffers();
    }

    int main(int argc, char** argv) {
      glutInit(&argc, argv);
      glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA);

      glutInitWindowSize(1920, 1080);

      glutInitWindowPosition(200, 200);

      int windowID = glutCreateWindow("MyFirstWindow");

      GLenum error = glewInit();
      if (error != GLEW_OK) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error:'s'\n", glewGetErrorString(error));
        return 1;
      }

      GLclampf Red = 0.0f, Green = 0.0f, Blue = 0.0f, Alpha = 0.0f;
      glClearColor(Red, Green, Blue, Alpha);

      glutDisplayFunc(renderScene);

      glutMainLoop();

      return 0;
    }
```

I also tested whether 'glewinfo' could find a corrosponding entry point for my platform.
For example, here I have the output for glBindBuffer:

```
$ glewinfo | grep glBindBuffer
glBindBuffer:                                                OK
glBindBuffersBase:                                           OK
glBindBuffersRange:                                          OK
glBindBufferBase:                                            OK
glBindBufferRange:                                           OK
glBindBufferARB:                                             OK
glBindBufferBaseEXT:                                         OK
glBindBufferOffsetEXT:                                       OK
glBindBufferRangeEXT:                                        OK
```

Here you can see that glBindBuffer shouldn't be undefined, if I understand glew correctly.

Comment: Could it be that there is something wrong with the linking of the functions?

Comment: You need to understand the difference between a header and a library. The error "not declared in this scope" during compilation indicates that there was no declaration in the header file. That has absolutely nothing to with whether the function exists in a library. If you try to use a function which is not present in any library, you'll get an undefined entry error during the link step, which follows compilation. (And you'll see that it's the linker complaining, not the compiler.)

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to my problem on the glew website:

```
"Note that if you are using GLEW together with GLUT, you have to include glew.h first."
```

http://glew.sourceforge.net/install.html

So I swapped the first two included and everything worked.

As it is however, I cannot continue to use my Visual Studio Code auto formatter function, as it sorts the included alphabetically each time.